# Expected Statement End If

Tags: if-statement, asp-classic, vbscript

I have the following code setup in a form and I'm getting the "Expected Statement" error. My first time doing this and thought I had the syntax correct, what am I missing?

```
            <%
            If Trim(oQuote("shipmeth"))="FREIGHT" Then 
                Response.Write "Freight" 
            ElseIf Trim(oQuote("shipmeth"))="THRSHLD" Then 
                Response.Write "Threshold"
            End If
            %>
```

Comment: What language is this? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: It looks like vba, vb or vbscript (the classic edition)

Comment: Looking at `Response.Write` I think it is ASP classic but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

When using nested 2-way conditionals, each conditional must be closed by its own `End If`:

```
If condition_A Then
  action_A
Else
  If condition_B Then
    action_B
  Else
    If condition_C Then
      action_C
    Else
      action_D
    End If 'condition_C
  End If 'condition_B
End If 'condition_A
```

Only an n-way conditional can be closed with a single `End If` (because it's just a single conditional):

```
If condition_A Then
  action_A
ElseIf condition_B Then
  action_B
ElseIf condition_C Then
  action_C
Else
  action_D
End If
```

However, this kind of n-way conditional only makes sense when you're checking different conditions, e.g.

```
If IsEmpty(a) Then
  ...
ElseIf b > 23 Then
  ...
```

When checking the same variable for different values it's better to use a `Select` statement as [Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16940735/1630171) suggested:

```
Select Case foo
  Case "a"
    'handle foo="a"
  Case "b", "d"
    'handle foo="b" as well as foo="d"
  Case Else
    'handle non-matches
End Select
```

Answer (score 2):

The first statement following the `If` must be on a new line;

```
If Trim(oQuote("shipmeth"))="FREIGHT" Then 
  Response.Write "Freight"
```

Following conditions can be on the same line but must use ElseIf

```
ElseIf Trim(oQuote("shipmeth"))="THRSHLD" Then Response.Write "Threshold"
ElseIf ...
```

I would suggest a more readable Case;

```
select case Trim(oQuote("shipmeth"))
    Case "THRSHLD"
        Response.Write "Threshold"
    Case "PREMTHRHLD"
        Response.Write "Premium Threshold"
    ...
end select
```

Which has the additional advantage of only ever executing `Trim(oQuote("shipmeth"))` once.

Comment: I've changed it to the code in orig post but it only produces an output for the first statement

Answer (score 1):

I think "else if" should be one word, like `elseif`

Answer (score 0):

You have nice answers here, I'll append just one more (lightly optimized) alternative.

```
strTest   = Trim(oQuote("shipmeth"))
strResult = "Unexpected"
If strTest ="FREIGHT" Then strResult = "Freight"
If strTest ="THRSHLD" Then strResult = "Threshold"
Response.Write strResult
```

EDIT

And just to clarify my thought, I hate nested `If..Then`, unfortunately no `GoTo Label` in VBScript, therefore above double comparison could be optimized with function.

```
strResult = "Unexpected"
MyResponse Trim(...), strResult
Response.Write strResult

Sub MyResponse(strIn, strOut)
    If strIn = "FREIGHT" Then
        strOut = "Freight" : Exit Sub
    End If
    If strIn = "THRSHLD" Then strOut = "Threshold"
End Sub
```

Comment: -0.49 for using "optimize" in context of code that happily compares `strTest` with "THRSHLD" (and 42 other values) after having just seen that `strTest` is equal to "FREIGHT".

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner - Storing `Trim` result in variable is mainly what I mean by "lightly optimized" (note: bold "lightly"). Of course, I agree about compares `strTest` with "42 other values". If that the case I'll use `Select` but for 2 values this is nearly enough.